# jQuery: keydown replicating text one character behind

Tags: jquery

The objective of [this jsfiddle snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/ps0604/dzSRR/19/) is to display in `<p/>` the text entered in `<input/>` every time the user keys in a character. It works with the exception that `<p/>` is always one character behind. What's wrong with this code?

The jQuery code:

```
var $input = $('<input />');
$('body').append($input);
var $p = $('<p/>');
$('body').append($p);
$input.keydown(function() {
    $p.text ($input.val());
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`keydown` fires as the key is pressed, and before the value is updated with the pressed key. You may wish to use `keyup()` instead:

```
$input.keyup(function() {
    $p.text ($input.val());
});
```

Or simplify to:

```
$input.keyup(function() {
    $p.text (this.value);
});
```

You could also manually append the last character (which works, so long as the last keypress isn't a backspace or delete:

```
$input.keydown(e){
    $p.val( this.value + String.fromCharCode(e.which));
});
```

But, frankly, that starts to become silly when you have to account for special characters (using shift, ctrl, alt or backspace and delete).